# Transaction rollback in stateless session EJB 3.0

Tags: java, transactions, ejb-3.0, rollback

I have a stateless session EJB as per 3.0 spec.

```
/*Remote Interface*/

package com.nseit.ncfm2.data.ejb;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import com.nseit.ncfm2.security.Audit;

@Remote
public interface ProductionDataChangesRequestsRemote {

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public boolean shiftCandidateDetails(String sourceNcfmId,
            String destinationNcfmId, Collection<String> specialCasesList, String shiftingRemarks, String user, Audit updtAudit) throws NamingException, SQLException;
}


/*Bean Class*/

package com.nseit.ncfm2.data.ejb;

import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
import javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagement;
import javax.ejb.TransactionManagementType;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import com.nseit.ncfm2.security.Audit;
import com.nseit.ncfm2.util.server.lookup.LookUpServerResources;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class ProductionDataChangesRequestsBean
 */
@Stateless(name = "ProductionDataChangesRequestsBean", mappedName = "ProductionDataChangesRequestsEJB")
@Remote(ProductionDataChangesRequestsRemote.class)
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class ProductionDataChangesRequestsBean implements
        ProductionDataChangesRequestsRemote {

/**
 * Default constructor.
 */
public ProductionDataChangesRequestsBean() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public boolean shiftCandidateDetails(String sourceNcfmId,
        String destinationNcfmId, Collection<String> specialCasesList,
        String shiftingRemarks, String user, Audit updtAudit)
        throws NamingException, SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

    int updtCnt = 0;

    boolean areDetailsShifted = false;

    try {
        ..............
        ..............
        ..............

        /* Start: update table-1 */
        ..............
        ..............
        ..............

        updtCnt = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        ..............
        ..............
        ..............

        /* End: update table-1 */


        /* Start: update table-2 */
        ..............
        ..............
        ..............

        updtCnt = pstmt.executeUpdate();
        ..............
        ..............
        ..............

        /* End: update table-2 */

        areDetailsShifted = true;

    } /*catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out
                .println("SQLException in ProductionDataChangesRequestsBean.shiftCandidateDetails(...) "
                        + e.getMessage());
        // e.printStackTrace();

        context.setRollbackOnly();

    } */finally {
        LookUpServerResources.closeStatement(pstmt);
        LookUpServerResources.closeConnection(conn);
    }

    return areDetailsShifted;
}

}
```

Currently, if the 1st table update succeeds and the 2nd table update gives an exception, a rollback is not taking place, i.e records in 1st table are updated.

I want the transaction to be rolled back in case an SQLException occurs (or for that matter, if any runtime exception occurs).

I tried two approaches :

1. Use of `context.setRollbackOnly()` in catch block for SQLException
2. Throwing the SQLException

In both the cases, the transaction didn't roll back.

How can I achieve this:

1. Without the usage of @ApplicationException annotation (as I do not have any application exceptions)
2. Without catching the SQLException and then calling `context.setRollbackOnly()`

Or what is the standard way?

Answer (score 3):

You will have to throw `RuntimeException`

Comment: This is just a suggestion as it's working for us; so why Downvote?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is to use underlying *JPA* for persistence rather then using JDBC.
*JPA* provides a standard OR mapping solution that's well-integrated into an EJB 3.x-compliant container.

Also from your code it reflects that you have `TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER` , but still managing transaction manually.

> In bean-managed transaction
>   demarcation, the code in the session
>   or message-driven bean explicitly
>   marks the boundaries of the
>   transaction. Although beans with
>   container-managed transactions require
>   less coding, they have one limitation:
>   When a method is executing, it can be
>   associated with either a single
>   transaction or no transaction at all.
>   If this limitation will make coding
>   your bean difficult, you should
>   consider using bean-managed
>   transactions.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are using JDBC API in your bean. I don't think container manages those JDBC transactions. For CMT, you'd have to invoke operations on a container managed entity manager for the rollback to work as expected.